# I want to get two jsonArray from one url by using String Request

Tags: android

```
private void loadCricketPlayer() {

    //getting the progressbar
    final ProgressBar cricketProgressBar = findViewById(R.id.cricketProgressBar);

    //making the progressbar visible
    cricketProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url_new,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    cricketProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                    try {
                        //getting the whole json object from the response
                        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);

                        JSONArray jArray = obj.getJSONArray("squad");

                        for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {

                            JSONObject jsonObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);


                            JSONArray bArray = obj.getJSONArray("players");
                            for (int j = 0; j < bArray.length(); j++){


                            JSONObject jsonObject1 = bArray.getJSONObject(j);
                            cricket_Player_POJO cricketPlayer = new cricket_Player_POJO(jsonObject1.getString("name"));

                            cricketListItem.add(cricketPlayer);

                            }

                         }

                        cricket_Player_List cricketList = new cricket_Player_List(cricketListItem, getApplicationContext());
                        cricketPLayerlistView.setAdapter(cricketList);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            //displaying the error in toast if occurrs
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

this is my json Array data for fetching the data from the server

This is my JSONARRAY example. For fetching the data:

```
{
  "squad": [
    {
        "name": "Australia",
        "players": [
            {
                "pid": 7252,
                "name": "Tim Paine"
            },
            {
                "pid": 489889,
                "name": "Pat Cummins"
            },
            {
                "pid": 5334,
                "name": "Aaron Finch"
            },
        ]
    }]
}
```

How can I Fetch this code Help me How can I do it  I am using volley for this and I want to fetch this data in the listview android

How can I Fetch this code Help me How can I do it  I am using volley for this and I want to fetch this data in the listview android

Comment: what is issue ?

Comment: I want to fetch both the jsonArray. Only 1 is coming first one where jsonData is equal to "squad"

Comment: can you past your out put ?

Comment: 12-10 19:00:04.643 22898-22898/walkmoney.app W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for players

Comment: see my answer you will get your output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace with this code

```
try {
                    //getting the whole json object from the response
                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);

                    JSONArray jArray = obj.getJSONArray("squad");

                    for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {

                        JSONObject jsonObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);


                        JSONArray bArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("players");
                        for (int j = 0; j < bArray.length(); j++){


                        JSONObject jsonObject1 = bArray.getJSONObject(j);
                        cricket_Player_POJO cricketPlayer = new cricket_Player_POJO(jsonObject1.getString("name"));

                        cricketListItem.add(cricketPlayer);

                        }

                     }

                    cricket_Player_List cricketList = new cricket_Player_List(cricketListItem, getApplicationContext());
                    cricketPLayerlistView.setAdapter(cricketList);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```